# Setting up LVM Volume Groups... hang

Tags: debian, lvm, root, failed

My Debian 7 System dosn't boot anymore. The boot stop with a kernel message like thisMy Debian 7 System dosn't boot anymore. The boot stop with a kernel message like this:

```
[.....] Setting up LVM Volume Groups...
```

The problem is a snapshot of my root volume. This snapshot is 100%.

How can I boot my system so that I can do `lvremove /dev/vg00/root--snap -f`.

Answer (score 1):

Try booting single user and then activating the volume group machinery manually.

Comment: This results in another error. Remounting root read writeable was the key.

Answer (score 0):

For the record. I've boot in single user mode, umount all lvm drives. Then and that was the jumping point I've remount / read writeable `mount / -o remount,rw`.

Then `lvremove -fv /dev/vg00/xyz` was working.